# doxygen: link to file which is not documented D

Tags: doxygen

I document a class member and want to link the path to a `.txt` file which is not contained in the configuration file, i.e., the file I want to link to is not listed in the `INPUT` and does not match any of the `FILE_PATTERNS`.

Is there a way to create a link to this file or do I have to list it under `INPUT` in the configuration file?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? You could tray the `<A HREF="...">` command in doxygen (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html) you should not forget to add the file to the `HTML_EXTRA_FILES` (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_files) so the original file lands in the output directory.

Comment: I use doxygen 1.9.6

Comment: 1.9.6 version should be OK though the current doxygen version is 1.9.8

Comment: @albert I did `/** See the file <A HREF="myFile.txt"> for details */` and doxygen reports `Unexpected end of comment while inside <a href=...>` tag. The link in the html output is working, however,  `for details` is the text highlighted in blue. which is what comes after the `<A HREF="myFile.txt">` tag in my case.

Comment: Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: Well it looks like the `<A ...` > tag is not closed so probably you need `/** See the file <A HREF="myFile.txt"> for details </A>*/`.

Comment: That fixed it. You can write this is an answer!